# Find Bayesian Nash Equilibria

Tags: game-theory, economics

A rich, honest, but mischievous father told his two sons that he had placed $10^n$ and $10^{n-1}$ in two envelopes respectively, where n ∈ $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$. The father then randomly handed each son one of the two envelopes with a probability of $0.5$. After both sons opened their envelopes, his father privately asked each son whether he wanted to switch his envelops with the one his brother had. If both sons agreed, then the envelopes were switched. Otherwise, each son kept the original envelop he received.

Find all pure strategy Bayesian Nash Equilibria.

What I did was to formulate the problem.

Type Spaces: $T_1=T_2=\{10^n,10^{n−1}\}$

Action Spaces: $A1=A2=\{S,S'\}$ where $S$ is switch and $S'$ is don't switch.

Strategy Spaces: $S_i:T_i\rightarrow A_i$ where $i=1,2$

I got $(S', SS)$ and $(S', S'S')$ for my Bayesian Nash equilibria. It means if 1st son chooses not to switch then 2nd son's strategy is to switch when he has $10^n$ or $10^{n-1}$. The other will be 1st son choose not to switch and 2nd son's strategy is not to switch when he has $10^n$ or $10^{n-1}$.

What's puzzling is that I didn't use when $n=\{1,\ldots,10\}$. Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: denotes ​ $\mapsto$ ​ "is an element of" ​ ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

Both wanting not to switch in any circumstances is a Nash equilibrium: neither can do better by changing strategy.

One wanting not to switch and the other wanting to switch in any circumstances is not a Nash equilibrium: for example the first son could do better by wanting to switch when his envelope has $10^0$.

Consider these examples when looking for Nash equilibria pure strategies:

- If the second son wants to switch when holding $10^9$, it is not a Nash equilibrium for the first son to want to switch when holding $10^{10}$
- If the first son wants not to switch when holding $10^{10}$ but does want to switch when holding $10^8$, it is not a Nash equilibrium for the second son to want to switch when holding $10^9$

Comment: You're right. So do i split them into cases to solve? Let's say 3 cases: when n = 1, n = 10 and n will be rest of the remaining numbers.

Comment: I could have added things like *If the second son wants not to switch when holding $10^{9}$ but does want to switch when holding $10^7$, it is not a Nash equilibrium for the first son to want to switch when holding $10^8$* and similarly for most of the smaller exponents.

Comment: You then need to put all these together, as they severely restrict the possible Nash equilibria.  It seems that a son's willingness to switch when seeing an envelope holds more then $10^0$ may always be exploitable by the other son.  So you may actually have Nash equilibria which only vary on a desire to switch or not to switch after seeing $10^0$.  There are four possibilities, and all of then result in no actual switching

Comment: Will an extensive tree diagram be useful in this case?